# Are multiple arrangements allowed on the same method with NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I am new to NSubstitute. The test fails because the second arrangement causes invocation of the first one and makes it fail even before the "act". I am not sure if i should make multiple arrangements on the same method. But I feel like It shouldn't be calling the first arrangement regardless, since the parameters don't match.

```
public interface IMediator
{
    Task<TResponse> Send<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

    Task Send(IRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));

    Task Publish<TNotification>(TNotification notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        where TNotification : INotification;
}

public class MyMessage : IRequest<MyResponse> {}

public class MyResponse {}

public class MyMessage2 : IRequest<MyResponse> {}

    [Fact]
    public async Task Mock_Fail() {
        var mediatr = Substitute.For<IMediator>();
        var myMessage = new MyMessage();
        var myMessage2 = new MyMessage();
        var myResponse = new MyResponse();
        var myResponse2 = new MyResponse();

        mediatr.Send(Arg.Any<MyMessage>())
            .Returns((ci) => {
                Assert.Same(myMessage, ci[0]); //That fails
                return myResponse;
            });

        mediatr.Send(Arg.Any<MyMessage2>())
            .Returns((ci) => {
                return myResponse2;
            });

       //Execution never reaches here
        var response = await mediatr.Send(myMessage);
        var response2 = await mediatr.Send(myMessage2);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd test this more like:

```
 mediatr.Send(myMessage)
        .Returns(ci => myResponse);

 mediatr.Send(myMessage2)
        .Returns(ci => myResponse2);
```

There are a few approaches to overriding previous stubs that throw, but I think the best approach is to avoid the problem where possible. :)

**EDIT after more info provided**: 
This looks like [a bug in NSubstitute's `Arg.Any` handling](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/291). A work around is to use `Arg.Is<MyMessage>(x => x!=null)` as shown in that issue description. Overall I would focus on stubbing more specifically to avoid the calls overlapping as per my original answer.

Comment: I would do so too but the test was for demonstrating NSubstitute's behaviour. Refactoring it to wrap around the problem has no point :)

Comment: Do you have a more realistic example of the problem? It is hard to advise without more context. In general, avoid the problem by changing ordering, worst case use a closure/Func you can change later or put more logic into the callback. Or see if the When Do syntax can help.

Comment: @Serguzest Thanks, looks like you've found a bug! Updated my answer with a link to the bug report.

Comment: I must be very lucky, It was my first day with Nsubstitute :)

Comment: Sorry you had such an inauspicious introduction. :-\ I'm not sure how fixable the bug is as `null` is a member of every reference type so NSubstitute can't differentiate the calls here. Happy to help you work around the issue (as per my initial answer, or by changing arrangement order so throw comes last, etc), please email me/NSub group if you need more info.

Comment: It is all right, I am rather grateful for the the fantastic library,  Arg.Is<MyMessage>(x => x!=null) seems like a legit work around.